# Handle Timer when incoming calls & SMS

Tags: android

I have started multiple Timers on the same screen.

When an incoming call or SMS comes, how can I handle the functioning of the timers.
The timer should continue running when the incoming call is being attended by the user.

Kindly provide your inputs/sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Timers is that they depend on the current Activity state, so if the activity has been completely obscured (like when a call arrives) it's onStop() method will be called, and Android doesn't guarantee that your app will continue running from that point.

The best solution to this is to use services. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) you have official Services guide.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. If you find any doc or Url about the implementation which you mentioned , kindly forward that.